# SQL/RPG DB2 i - errors in Systools.HttpPostClob

Tags: api, ibm-midrange, db2-400

SQL/RPG DB2 i - errors in Systools.HttpPostClob

Program compiles clean, but get two errors in job log.

```
 dcl-pr MYTEST  ExtPgm;                                          
     dcl-parm ParmIn      char(3000) CONST Options(*VarSize);     
     dcl-parm ParmOut     char(5000);                            
 end-pr;                                                          

 dcl-s  JsonStr     char(5500);
 dcl-s  PostUrl     varchar(2048);        
 dcl-s  HttpHead  varchar(2048);        
 dcl-s  Data        varchar(2048);        

 // use SQL to call API.                                                       
     Exec SQL SELECT JSON_VAL                                                  
     INTO :JsonStr   
     FROM Json_Table(                                                          
     Systools.HttpPostClob(                                                    
       :PostUrl,                                                              
       CAST (:HttpHead AS CLOB(10000)),                                     
       CAST (:ParmIn AS CLOB(5000000) )                                        
      ), '$' COLUMNS(JSON_VAL VARCHAR(1000) path '$.json')) as x ;             
================================================================================
```

Errors:

-Attributes of field   HVR00003 and *N not compatible.
-CAST from CHAR FOR BIT DATA to CLOB not supported.

No sign off HVR00003 in compile listing or while debugging. Also not sure where I would be CASTing "from CHAR FOR BIT DATA to CLOB"?

Thanks!

Comment: DSPSYSVAL QCCSID....is it 65535 by chance?

Comment: also I don't think you should be using JSON_TABLE, if all you want back is the JSON string...

Comment: 65535. No way I'm changing this...  had to run CHGJOB CCSID(1132) first. Dawh... I saw this issue before. Don't know why it runs best in Loa not Thai? :-)
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMGV_3.1.0/com.ibm.cics.ts31.doc/dfht8/dfht80j.htm

Comment: also https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=b0aa5ad4-3d0a-4897-90eb-eab8dd1ceb7b

Comment: and probably don't need JSON table anymore.